# Does the scheduler determine which processes can re-enter the CPU after they're blocked?

Tags: operating-system, scheduler

I am studying for my OS midterm and I have a question in the study guide that I am not 100% sure about.

**The scheduler exists to:**
*A. Service interrupts.

 B. Select the next process to enter the CPU.

 C. Create a new process.

 D. Remove unused processes from the system.

 E. Determine which blocked processes can enter the CPU.

 F. B and E.*

**So I know B (Select the next process to enter the CPU) is true.**

The part that I am not sure about is the E option. I am not sure what this actually means.

Does this actually imply the case where, say after `scanf`, user input is expected, and the process remains blocked ?

Does waiting for that input actually means determining ? Or is the scheduler actively involved determining whether that input is entered ?

How would you answer this question? B or F?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the process states carefully you will notice that a blocked process can never enter a CPU directly. Its only when a process has entered the **ready** state, it can enter the CPU to be executed.

[image]

When a process is in **blocked/waiting** state it is basically waiting either for an external event like input from user or waiting in some I/O device queue for some I/O service. Now once that event occurs it will go to **ready** state and the scheduler(**short term scheduler to be precise**) job is to decide which process to pick out of those that are in **ready** state. So statement **E** is wrong.